# How can I determine which model contains x, y coordinates in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

I noob in Android `ARCore`. I took sample `(hello_ar_java)` from `ARCore sdk` and ran it. This sample show a model when user taps on screen (on detected plane).
But I want to remove the model when user taps on it. How I can do it? 
Has `ARCore` mechanisms for this or need to transform `OpenGL` coordinates to screen x,y?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with OpenGL. Take a look at [Intersection test for ray picking in opengl es for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788969/intersection-test-for-ray-picking-in-opengl-es-for-android) for how to test screen coordinates against 3D objects.